# iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS

Tags: debian

[image]

I am using a modified version of debian GNU/linux 10 called huayra which is an operating system that is included in the computers granted by the government of Argentina I have the problem iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS I have placed the command cat /proc/acpi/wakeup and the list that is in the photo appears okay if you look at the last device in the list (CNVW) it is disabled but if you look in sysfs node it has the same numbers as the problem that won't let me boot the system (0000:00:0c.0) I think that if I enable CNVW my system will be able to boot

Comment: instead of asking the same question again with a little more info, why not edit the previous question? anyway, use `acpitool` - though, not sure what enabling CNVW wakeup will do

Answer (score 2):

"BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS" means roughly: "BIOS contains country-specific WiFi transmission power tables but no single basic table that would be legal to use worldwide". This is a known non-critical message whose priority is downgraded on newer kernels so that it only appears in debug logs, not in typical boot messages.

WRDS is an ACPI table that describes the basic WiFi transmitter power levels that would be legal to use anywhere in the world. WGDS is another table that complements WRDS, indicating how much higher transmitter power can be used in specific regions of the world.

Generally, the WiFi base station (also known as Access Point) will transmit a country code, that tells all hosts in range which channels and transmit power levels are legal to use.

The error message indicates that the Intel WiFi driver has failed to read the basic power level information, and so it will err on the side of caution and use minimal power levels until it hears a country code from a base station. That means an initial connection to a base station that is hiding its SSID (so your system must transmit first to connect to it instead of just listening for it) might require you to be a bit closer to the base station than otherwise would. It should have nothing to do with being unable to boot.

Because the Intel WiFi driver `iwlwifi` is associated with the PCI device ID `0000:00:0c.0`, the ACPI ID `CNVW` must mean the Intel WiFi chip in your system. The fact that its wakeup status is `disabled` means that the chip either does not support Wake-on-WiFi or that feature is not currently enabled: in other words, your laptop cannot be woken from a sleep or power-off state by a WiFi transmission.

This is probably a **good** thing: you don't want the laptop to wake up inside its bag if it happens to catch a random WiFi transmission, heating up and running its battery down for no good reason.

If you are trying to set up your laptop to wake up from sleep or power-off state for some reason, the recommended way would probably be a command like `iw phy phy0 wowlan enable [wake-up conditions...]`, or configuring something like WPA-Supplicant to also enable WiFi wakeups for you. The driver would then automatically enable the ACPI setting you see in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`: that file is more like a debugging interface for troubleshooting ACPI wake-up problems.

---

If your actual main problem is that the graphical user interface is not starting, then I'm afraid you're looking at entirely wrong place.

First, you should run `systemctl get-default` to see if the system is even configured to start the GUI automatically or not. If the response is `graphical.target`, then the system is at least attempting to start the GUI. If the response is `multi-user.target`, the system is currently configured to start in text-only mode, and `systemctl set-default graphical.target` might change that persistently - but you probably should test the transition with `systemctl isolate graphical.target` first.

If the system is trying to start the GUI but failing, you might run `systemctl` with no options and look at the resulting list of system services. Are any of those displayed in red? That would mean those services are failing. The next step would be to run `systemctl status <whatever.service>` (replacing `<whatever.service>` with the actual service name) to see the current status of the failing service, and a few last log messages produced by it. To see more log messages from the service, try `journalctl -u <whatever.service>`.

Comment: how can i place this command iw phy phy0 wowlan enable [wake-up conditions...] I place it and it gives me an error of order not found

Comment: First, check your hardware specifications and see if your WiFi chip even supports Wake-on-WiFi at all. Then read http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw and replace `[wake-up conditions...]` with the actual wake-up conditions you want to apply. Third, ensure you have the package that contains the `iw` command installed on your system.